# Django ModelForm not saving data that is added to request.POST or through form.save(commit=False)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have django form that submitted to the view that displays it and want to add some data to it before saving it but it seems not be working.

**models.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=145, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    prof = models.ForeignKey('Profile', null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ModuleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ['name',  'semester']
```

**views.py**:

I have tried adding `prof` to `request.POST` before passing it to `moduleform` but it saves every other data submitted from the *HTML* except `prof`

```
prof = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    mtb = request.POST._mutable
    request.POST._mutable = True
    request.POST['prof'] = str(prof.id)
    request.POST._mutable = mtb
    moduleform = ModuleForm(request.POST)
    moduleform.save()
```

I have also tried saving with `commit=False` but `prof` is still not getting added.

```
moduleform.save(commit=False)
moduleform.prof = prof
moduleform.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example from [django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
form = PartialAuthorForm(request.POST)
author = form.save(commit=False)
author.title = 'Mr'
author.save()
```

In your case (untested):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ModuleForm(request.POST)
    object = form.save(commit=False)
    object.prof = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    object.save()
```

**EDIT:**
To clarify your comment on my answer:

```
moduleform.save(commit=False)
moduleform.prof = prof
moduleform.save()
```

Does not work because the form will never save `prof` on the instance because it is not part of the `fields`. This is why you HAVE TO set the `prof` on the model-level.

Comment: I have done this as explained in the last part of the question.

Comment: @Yax: No, you save the form, not the object!

Comment: Why didn't I see that? Poor me. Thanks a whole lot.